# The lambda expression is unused

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

While using Android's `Switch`, I was attaching a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to it and got this warning

> The lambda expression is unused. If you mean a block, you can use 'run {...}'

Here' the code snippet:

```
switchAction.setOnCheckedChangeListener({
    _, isChecked ->
    {
        preferences.userStatus = isChecked
        switchToggleVisibility(isChecked)
        if (isChecked) {
            fetchStats()
            getOrders()
        } else {
            releaseOrder()
        }
    }
})
```

Using `run` does fix this warning, but does anyone know the cause behind this? How is the lambda expression unused?

Answer (score 49):

You're mixing Java's lambda notation with Kotlin's lambda notation, creating a lambda that returns another nested lambda in this case. The correct and idiomatic syntax would look like this:

```
switchAction.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    preferences.userStatus = isChecked
    switchToggleVisibility(isChecked)
    if (isChecked) {
        fetchStats()
        getOrders()
    } else {
        releaseOrder()
    }
}
```

Taking all the noise out, a normal lambda looks like this:

```
{ arg1, arg2 -> returnValue } // Type: (A, B) -> C
```

You did this:

```
{ arg1, arg2 -> { returnValue } } // Type: (A, B) -> (() -> C)
```

Which could also be written like this:

```
{ arg1, arg2 -> { -> returnValue } } // Type: (A, B) -> (() -> C)
```

This notation makes it a bit clearer that the lambda doesn't return the return value, but returns another lambda with no parameters that returns the return value.

Usually, this would get caught by the compiler as a wrong return type, but in your case, the return value of the lambda is not used. So, you're just creating the inner lambda without returning or running it, that's why you're getting a warning.

Comment: In case of multiple statement, we have to use curly braces right ?

Comment: @ShijenN I'm not quite sure what you're asking? In Kotlin, a lambda _always_ has exactly one set of curly braces, which opens before the parameter list and closes behind the last statement or return expression of the lambda. The braces have to be there, no matter how many statements the lambda contains.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about if- and when-expressions? With those, you can indeed leave out the curly braces if the body is made of just one statement/expression, but have to include them if there are multiple statements inside the body. Those are not lambdas, though.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the

```
_, isChecked ->
    { ... }
```

Must be changed to

```
_, isChecked ->
    preferences.userStatus = isChecked
    switchToggleVisibility(isChecked)
    if (isChecked) {
        fetchStats()
        getOrders()
    } else {
        releaseOrder()
    }
```

So just remove the curly braces because else you just create a block which isn't executed at all.
Alternatively you could also do

```
_, isChecked ->
    run {
        preferences.userStatus = isChecked
        switchToggleVisibility(isChecked)
        if (isChecked) {
            fetchStats()
            getOrders()
        } else {
            releaseOrder()
        }
    }
```